# How to catch different elements?

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

I'm using [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) for work with html and faced one problems: I have table of different elements (few `select` and many `input`). I need to check the values of all elements in the table. With input no problem (`$('input[type="text"]')`), but how to check in one time `select` and `input` values.the problem is that the smart does not provide any additional options for `{html_options}`. May be there is some `AND` structure for jQuery selectors?

Comment: Can you frame your question properly please ??

Comment: @sushanthreddy i just need to select in the same time input and select. Something like $('input[type="text"]&&select').val()

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible routes here:

- **Extend your selector** with `add`, e.g.

`$('input[type="text"]').add('select').doSomething()`

- **Use a common class** for all `input` and `select` elements, e.g.

`$('.my_input_class').doSomething()`

Of course this assumes that you are using common properties/methods on your selection afterwards. For instance, you'd be able to call `val()` to retrieve the values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the same functionality to two selectors you can this approach..

```
$('input[type=text] , select').addClass('classname')
```

You can use a comma to add the same functionality to multiple selectors..